# how to dont call contruvtor Inherits in vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to call  Dim objFkkiNinteiJokyoRpt As New A(objCsv) in class C. But class A Inherits  Common. If now call contructor will An error occurred.Because type Object  C.CsvGenerator diference type Object in common. I thnk now stop call to contructor common (or any other way) but i dont know how to do. Helf me please. Sorry because my english so bad

```
Public Class A Inherits Common
            Public _objCsv As C.CsvGenerator
    
            Friend Sub New(ByVal objCsv As C.CsvGenerator)
                _objCsv = objCsvGenerator
            End Sub
    
            Public Sub New()
            End Sub
            End Sub
            Public Sub New(ByVal objRSReportObj As Object)
                MyBase.New(objRSReportObj)
                InitializeReport()
            End Sub
     End Class

    Public Class C
       Private Function SelectCSV
            Dim objCsv As New CsvGenerator("") 
            Dim objFkkiNinteiJokyoRpt As New A(objCsv)
       End Function
       Friend Class CsvGenerator
                Inherits cmShare.cmObject
       End Class
     End Class

  Public Class Common
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
  
          Public Sub New(ByVal objRSReport As Object)

            MyBase.New(objRSReport)
        End Sub
  
    End Class
```

Comment: You don't need `Class Common` at all. Just remove it.

Comment: sorry, my project need Class Common. Every class must Inherits Common. This is problem :'(

Comment: "Every class must Inherits Common" - there is no reason for doing that.

Comment: i know that, but this is  other company 's  source code. i only outsource ;((. Can you helf me pro

Comment: No, I cannot help you.

Comment: When Common is calling MyBase.New() What is MyBase? Common doesn't inherit anything.

Comment: @Mary it inherits (implicitly) from `Object`.  Calling `MyBase.New()` in that context is legal, if pointless.

Comment: @Mary. I only add code sample. In fact, common is nesscesary to inheritance some func in common. When i call  Dim objFkkiNinteiJokyoRpt As New A(objCsv).  always call to common. Public Sub New(ByVal objRSReportObj As Object) can understand CsvGenerator("") , so have error. Do you have any advice for me ?